# Need to pass byte array through @actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, action

I'm getting a null value when trying to pass a byte array through an action link to the controller. I'm new to MVC. Basically, i need to download the image (byte array) as a pdf.

View:

```
if(Model.checkimage != null){ 
    @html.ActionLink("Download PDF", "DownloadPDF", "Transaction", new {Check =  Model.checkimage});
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult downloadPDF (byte[] Check)
```

Comment: Even if this was possible, it would almost certainly exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. Pass the ID of the file to the method.

Comment: Always nice to find your exact question already asked on SO

Answer (score 3):

Mady's answer is the better alternative, but if it isn't viable (e.g. you aren't storing the byte array somewhere else), then you can always Base-64 encode the byte array into a string, and pass that into the action method

```
System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.checkimage)
```

You'll have to convert it back into a byte array in your action method.

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String(imageData)
```

Base-64 encoding does add some bloat (~33% more bytes); also, some browsers have limits on how long URLs can get, so you may want to make sure you aren't getting close to any of those limits.

Answer (score 1):

Passing byte array as an action method argument is not a good idea. if you are retrieving those from data base or a file then probably you can pass some unique identifier or file path as an argument & then in controller write the logic.